# sendmail smart host not working on server

Tags: centos, sendmail

I am trying to set up mail relay on a server to use relay.jangosmtp.net.

I have done this before on many other servers but have never had this issue.  I updated my sendmail.mc with this:

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
define(`SMART_HOST', `relay.jangosmtp.net')dnl
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
MAILER(procmail)dnl
dnl MAILER(cyrusv2)dnl
```

I then ran `make -C /etc/mail`

For some reason after I restart sendmail and try to send an email it does not use the smart host relay.  This is what I get in the logs:

```
Oct 14 17:54:17 ip-10-191-148-198 sendmail[17476]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@01:00:00
Oct 14 17:54:17 ip-10-191-148-198 sm-msp-queue[17484]: starting daemon (8.14.4): queueing@01:00:00
Oct 14 17:54:39 ip-10-191-148-198 sendmail[17487]: r9EHsdc3017487: from=apache, size=332, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=<201310141754.r9EHsdc3017487@ip-10-191-148-198>, relay=apache@localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for two pairs of `from=` and `to=` sendmail log entries. The second `to=` log entry should show relay via the smart host.

The first pair should be generated by `submit.cf` sendmail and the second by `sendmail.cf` sendmail.

You can connect `from=` and `to=` log entries using queue id (e.g. `r9EH0clP016385`).

Comment: I have updated my question to include the full log entry that is output whenever an email is sent. I don't see a `to=` anywhere in there.

Comment: Procedure for partial debug: as use apache send a test message from command line in verbose mode. `(echo Subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -v -- john.doe@example.net`

Comment: OK that worked and I received the email in my gmail box.  So it is not working when I use a php script to send the email.  Any idea on what could be the cause of that?

Comment: Have you changes email settings in `php.in` file? [especially sendmail_path] http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first things that I checked.  I ended up just using phpMailer to get it done.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because the problem is not with sendmail it is with my php settings.  This answer helped me diagnose that.